# Connect to HTTPS servers using Racket

Tags: https, racket

When I try to connect to a webserver over HTTPS using Racket's `net/http-client` package, the following happens:

#### With `#t`

```
➜  code  racket                
Welcome to Racket v6.2.
> (require net/http-client)
> (http-sendrecv "google.com" "/" #:ssl? #t)
ssl-connect: requested protocol not supported
  requested: 'auto
  context...:
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/openssl/mzssl.rkt:608:0: make-raw-context
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/openssl/mzssl.rkt:482:18
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/racket/private/more-scheme.rkt:264:2: call-with-exception-handler
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/net/http-client.rkt:294:0: http-sendrecv92
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

#### With `'tls`

```
> (require net/http-client)
> (http-sendrecv "google.com" "/" #:ssl? 'tls)
ssl-connect: requested protocol not supported
  requested: 'tls
  context...:
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/openssl/mzssl.rkt:608:0: make-raw-context
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/openssl/mzssl.rkt:482:18
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/racket/private/more-scheme.rkt:264:2: call-with-exception-handler
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/net/http-client.rkt:294:0: http-sendrecv92
   /usr/local/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

#### Output of `(supported-client-protocols)`

```
> (require openssl)
> (supported-client-protocols)
'()
```

How do I use `http-sendrecv` to connect to a HTTPS server?

Comment: In this situtation check `ssl-available?` and `ssl-load-fail-reason` in a REPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Linux, this might happen because Racket doesn't know about the version of the OpenSSL library you have installed. Confirm by checking `ssl-load-fail-reason`, as @soegaard suggested.

A workaround is to install the OpenSSL development package (`libssl-dev` or `openssl-devel` or something like that), which includes a versionless shared library symlink.

Comment: In my particular case that was the issue, I forgot to install the devel package. In addition, had I specified `--enable-openssl` I think the configure script would have errored when it couldn't find openssl.

Comment: Racket locates the shared library at run time, not at build time. There is no `--enable-openssl` option; the configure script should have raised an error, but didn't for some reason (I've reported that as a bug).

Comment: Yeah it looks like I was mistaken about the `--enable-openssl`. In fact `configure` will accept any fake `--enable-...` flags silently.

However I was able to resolve the issue by rebuilding Racket after install `openssl-devel`, which might suggest the foreign library interface isn't used with openssl... I wouldn't know how to check this one way or the other.

Answer (score 3):

Use `'tls` instead of `#t`.

```
> (require net/http-client)
> (http-sendrecv "google.com" "/" #:ssl? 'tls)
#"HTTP/1.1 302 Found"
'(#"Location: https://www.google.dk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=10q1Ve3dMsm4sQGd_KioAQ"
  #"Cache-Control: private"
  #"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  #"P3P: CP=\"This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info.\""
  #"Date: Sun, 26 Jul 2015 21:02:15 GMT"
  #"Server: gws"
  #"Content-Length: 259"
  #"X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block"
  #"X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"
  #"Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:TM=1437944535:LM=1437944535:V=1:S=_FmpeZRsEpdAXW_-; expires=Tue, 25-Jul-2017 21:02:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com"
  #"Set-Cookie: NID=69=GDETUcLzNFvaXS9uD9fxW_rA-k3ywu9vsb8VVCBUUOrbL-BmWjxpj0duYXoNZyH0EHMt54dmVnn3xPJvESfM4tLy_T8DYCsas_9dloNB9s6NfcxmbeD4DQzAAou0ly_l; expires=Mon, 25-Jan-2016 21:02:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly"
  #"Connection: close")
#<input-port:pipe>
```